# Int array[][] doesn't save to / load from text file

Tags: android

I wrote this code to save the values of / load values to int arrayScore[10][1000] on/from a text file (ScoreFile.txt), for when the app is closed/opened.

saveData is contained in the onStop() method and loadData is contained in the onCreate() method. When I open/run/close the app, no exception is thrown. The toast says indeed "Data loaded" and "Data saved".

The values of arrayScore[][] do change during the runtime of the app, which is confirmed by these new values appearing on-screen. So during runtime everything works fine.

However, the values of the last session are **not loaded** when a new session is started, and after that last session ScoreFile.txt is **nowhere to be found** on my phone.

```
File scoreFile = new File("ScoreFile.txt");

public void saveData() {
   try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(scoreFile);

        int p, q;
        for (p = 0; p <= 9; p++) {
            for (q = 0; q <= 999; q++) {
                output.println(arrayScore[p][q]);
            }
        }
   } catch (Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Exception savedData", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } finally {
   }
   Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void loadData() {
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(scoreFile);

        int p, q;
        for (p = 0; p <= 9; p++) {
            for (q = 0; q <= 999; q++) {
               arrayScore[p][q] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception loadData", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the toasts, log the errors properly and then share your logcat. I'm sure this will be a common issue

Answer (score 0):

A few of points. First, do you have permission to write create a file at that location? Ordinarily, you'd preface the name of your file with the path to internal/external storage for your app, and check that it exists before you do anything. For example (there are many ways to write a file):

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "ScoreFile.txt");
try (final FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)){
    fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //for...
        fos.write(/*...*/);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second, have you declared permission for reading and writing to the filesystem in your manifest? You may need runtime permissions for this as well on Oreo+.

Third,of course you see the "Data Saved" toast, because it runs no matter what. Replace it with `throws new RuntimeException(e);` in your `catch` and see whether your app crashes. If it does, check LogCat and add the exception to your question.

Fourth, you may need to call `flush()` on your `PrintWriter`